# ADO - VSTeam -update user license command not working

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, devops

I am trying to use powershell VSTeam module to work on user's license rotation. I am not able to run update-VSTeamUserEntitlement command, throws an error immediately. Surprisingly remove and get command works fine.

```
Update-VSTeamUserEntitlement -Email xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com -License stakeholder


Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "Update user" on target "xxxxxxxxx" (xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com)".
[Y] Yes [A] Yes to All [N] No [L] No to All [S] Suspend [?] Help (default is "Y"): Y
WARNING: The request indicated a Content-Type of "application/json-patch+" for method type "PATCH" which is not supported. Valid content types for this method are:
application/json-patch+json.
**Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The request indicated a Content-Type of \"application/json-patch+\" for method type \"PATCH\" which is not supported. Valid
content types for this method are: application/json-patch+json.*","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssRequestContentTypeNotSupportedException,**
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi","typeKey":"VssRequestContentTypeNotSupportedException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\VSTeam\7.4.0\vsteam.functions.ps1:266 char:18
+ $resp = Invoke-RestMethod @params
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

can someone please help?

Comment: Feel free to let me know if the vsteam 7.2.0 can work for you.

Answer (score 0):

From the Log, you are using the PowerShell Module VSTeam 7.4.0.

I can reproduce the same issue.

The root cause of this issue is from the Configuration file of the VSTeam 7.4.0.

File name: [vsteam.functions.ps1](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/VSTeam/7.4.0/Content/vsteam.functions.ps1)

It uses the following contenttype:

[image]

The correct format is `application/json-patch+json`.

For a workaround, you can unintall the Vsteam module 7.4.0. And change to use the VSTeam version 7.2.0.

Based on my check, the contenttype in VSteam version 7.2.0 is correct.

```
Uninstall-Module -Name Vsteam -RequiredVersion 7.4.0

Install-Module -Name VSTeam -RequiredVersion 7.2.0
```

Then you can run the script successfully.

[image]

I suggest that you can report this issue in the [VSteam Module Github issue](https://github.com/MethodsAndPractices/vsteam/issues).

**Update:**

> it doesn't change the accesslevel though the o/p says "updated user license to stakeholder" , in the backend it doesn't do that operation. Have you verified this?

Yes. I also noticed this issue now.

You can add the parameter in the script:

```
Update-VSTeamUserEntitlement -Email xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com -License stakeholder -Verbose
```

Then you can see the backend steps in the script.

For example:

[image]

Note: The response : `isSuccess=False` So it can't work as expected.

The backend steps is running this Rest API: [User Entitlements - Update User Entitlement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user-entitlements/update-user-entitlement?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

I tried the same body and URL in Postman, it can work as expected.
[image]

So this module may have other problems. I suggest that you can also mention this issue in your Github ticket.

For a workaround, you can directly use the Rest API to update the Access Level.

```
PATCH https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/userentitlements/{userId}?api-version=6.0-preview.3
```

**Update2:**

PowerShell sample:

```
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/ORG/_apis/userentitlements/userid?api-version=6.0-preview"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$JSON = @'
[
  {
    "from": "",
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/accessLevel",
    "value": {
      "accountLicenseType": "Stakeholder",
      "licensingSource": "account"
    }
  }
    
]
'@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method PATCH -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json-patch+json
```

Comment: thanks much checking this for me. I have followed your suggestion and downgraded to 7.2 and command works perfectly fine. However it doesn't change the accesslevel though the o/p says "updated user license to stakeholder" , in the backend it doesn't do that operation. Have you verified this?

Comment: @Thahif. Yes, you are right. i can confirm this issue. Please refer to my update.

Comment: Hi Kevin- thank you for confirming. how can I get userID in above PATCH command? 
also I believe , I should be calling something like below?

Comment: You can use this rest api to get the UserID https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user-entitlements/search-user-entitlements?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

Comment: also I believe , I should be calling something like below?
Invoke-RestMethod -uri https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/xxxxxxxxxx/_apis/userentitlements/xxxxx/api-version=6.0-preview.3/  -Method PATCH -ContentType "application/json-patch+" -Headers $header -body $body

Comment: Sure. Will provide a sampe for you

Comment: @Thahif. You can refer to the update2

Comment: Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method PATCH -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json-patch+json

operationResults                                                                                   isSuccess userEntitlement
----------------                                                                                   --------- ---------------
{@{isSuccess=False; errors=System.Object[]; userId=706ee0ca-f728-xxxxx-9289-cxxxxxxxx; result=}}     False @{id=706ee0ca-f728-6daa-9289-xxxxxxxxxx; user=; accessLevel=; lastAccessedDat...
doesnt update

Comment: Can you run the PowerShell successfully? In my side, the PowerShell script can update the access level successfully

Comment: Indeed I executed the same powershell snippet you provided. I just pasted the last command o/p.

Comment: any thoughts here?

Comment: According to the test, the same Powershell can work for me, not sure why it doesn’t work for you, have you created a PAT with sufficient permissions? I suggest that you can provide more details .

Comment: my PAT has FULL access and I am running the same code, not sure what's happening.. :(